# Tcp/IP Socket Exception

Tags: c#, networking

I have Sever-Client application which used to send and receive sms, Which working fine till last month.But after that I got TCP/Ip socket exception. I debug server application and found exception:

**System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)**

I got same exception on client when I debug more.
I gone through many threads similar to this, People suggest this is network related issue as Firewall/NAT/Antivirus blocking port, due to this connection between client & server get disturb.
I used 2999 port,and multiple clients communicating with server on same port.
Any clues? what is exact cause?

Comment: Have you tried looking at what's happening at the network level with Wireshark? If not, please do so and include that information in your question.

Comment: Also, if it really was working perfectly till last month, the only changes that make sense *are* firewall/nat/antivirus blocking port configuration changes.

Comment: Did the host possibly change to https?

Comment: @ Jon Skeet No I haven't used Wireshark will use it today.And then I will post related information.Thanks

Comment: @ Jason If firewall is blocking then problem should be permanent but sometimes its works.

Comment: @ Induster I checked its not changed to https.

Comment: Initialy client works perfect but after  sometime(after ~ 2 hr.) its throws exception and trying to restart, but unable to reconnect. After more debugging I found that server also get same exception.

Answer (score 1):

Does this happen all the time now or just sometimes? if it just happens every now and again what i would do is put it in a try catch statment and when this error is thrown reconnect and try again and log that it happend and when, also everything that was going on when it was thrown that way you can go back and figure out what the problem is when you get more info on when its being thrown. if its happening all the time then somthing is forcing your connection to close witch could be a firewall so for testing i would turn off all your firewalls and antiviruses.

Comment: This happen sometimes.I have implemented logs in my application(try,catch), and on exception I restart client to connect it again, sometimes this works and sometimes client fails to connect.

Comment: Is it different computers or the same computer that causes this error? or anywhere are you not looping back and everything just ends without closing the socket?  if you could post some of your code it might help.

Comment: Yes Server is on different computer and client exist on different different computers.